# Python TimedRotatingFileHandler backup count to 0 is not worrking

Tags: python, logging

I created the `TimedRotatingFileHandler` for the logging module with the backup count as 0 in the Flask server. However the first log file generated includes all the logging information. But the rest of the log files contains the logs as desired.

This is the code I've used:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='logs/img-search.log',
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    datefmt='%m-%d-%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
)

hndlr = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    "logs/img-search.log",
    when='M',
    interval=1,
    backupCount=0
)

logging.getLogger(__name__).addHandler(hndlr)

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

If I create a custom handler and append the TimedRotatingFIleHandler to it, the files which the server serves are not getting added in the log file. Instead getting printed on the console.

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# add a file handler
fh = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler("logs/img-search.log",when='M',interval=1,backupCount=0)
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create a formatter and set the formatter for the handler.
frmt = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(frmt)
# add the Handler to the logger
log.addHandler(fh)
```

Here is a snippet of code getting printed on the console instead of the log file.

```
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
192.168.1.6 - - [12/Jun/2015 08:51:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.6 - - [12/Jun/2015 08:56:35] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.6 - - [12/Jun/2015 08:56:35] "GET /static/js/jquery-1.11.2/jquery-1.11.2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.6 - - [12/Jun/2015 08:56:35] "GET /static/js/main/main.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.6 - - [12/Jun/2015 08:56:35] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
192.168.1.6 - - [12/Jun/2015 08:56:35] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: Please, whenever you post code, use the code sample wrapper (CTRL + K). ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you set up your loggers the `basicConfig` will create a `FileHandler` that writes all logs to `logs/img-search.log` and additionally you set up `TimedRotatingFileHandlers` which should create one file per minute...

If you don't want the first file, just remove the `filename` arg from `basicConfig` like this:

```
# configures the root logger:
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    datefmt='%m-%d-%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
)

hndlr = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    "logs/img-search.log",
    when='M',
    interval=1,
    backupCount=0
)

# makes a new logger named as the current module and adds hndlr to it
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.addHandler(hndlr)
```

This will write all logging output to your console. Additionally for everything that uses `log` (so a logger with the name of your current module) it will also write its messages to different files each minute.

If you don't want the output on your console either but really only the output in those timed files you shouldn't use `basicConfig` anymore. `basicConfig` (as its name says) is just for the two basic standard cases where you want all output on console or in a file. As soon as you want something different you should just set your loggers up as you like, e.g. like this:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    datefmt='%m-%d-%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
)
hndlr = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    "logs/img-search.log",
    when='M',
    interval=1,
    backupCount=0
)
hndlr.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(hndlr)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

A couple more words about the `log = logging.getLogger(__name__)` line... this will get you a logger named as the current file which hierarchically is **below the root logger**. Settings on `log` will not apply and log stuff from other modules / libraries as they in general don't use loggers with the name of your module! If you want to globally configure logging, you should configure the root logger instead of `log` like this: `root = logging.getLogger()` (then do all the stuff above on `root` instead of `log`). You don't need to do them again for your individual file loggers like `log` then. You can just get your individual logger like `log = logging.getLogger(__name__)` and then call `log.debug(...)` without configuring it first. The logs will bubble up to your root logger and be logged as intended. Even the logs that just use `logging.debug(...)`.

As you see logging quickly becomes complicated as it has so many options. I recommend going through the [logging tutorials](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) to really understand how messages are logged and where to configure them. Flask has it's own `app.logger` object that it seems to use.

Comment: I'm maintaining this logging on the flask server. When I remove the filename on the basicconfig(), the files which the Flask server serves are not getting logged in. Instead all the msgs are printed on the console. @Jorn Hees
For example, These below messages are printed on the console.
06-12-2015 08:19:48 AM: INFO:  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
06-12-2015 08:19:48 AM: INFO:  * Restarting with stat
06-12-2015 08:19:49 AM: INFO: 192.168.1.6 - - [12/Jun/2015 08:19:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: yes, sorry your question doesn't really say what you want, so my answer was a guess. If you neither want to see the output on console nor in a file you shouldn't really use `basicConfig` anymore... it's just a "shortcut" for quickly getting `logging` up. i'll update my answer in a second.

Comment: Hees I've edited my question with the complete details. Please check it out